# Jenkins + sonar + checkstyle/findbugs/PMD

Tags: jenkins

Доброго времени суток ! Интересует такой вопрос, как использовать checkstyle/findbugs/PMD прагины в сонаре. Т.е. у меня есть настроеные дженкинс+сонар, джоба ранает сканер, передает параметры и т.д. но результат скана одинаковый... что с установлеными плагинами, что без. Надо как-то дополнительно писать в джобе юзать эти плагины ?
Что есть в джобе:

```
# Required metadata
sonar.projectKey=test-java-3
sonar.projectName=test-java-3
sonar.projectVersion=1.0

# Description of project (optional)
sonar.projectDescription=test Java part

# Comma-separated paths to directories with sources (required)
sonar.sources=src

sonar.language=java


# Encoding of the source files
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
```

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Надо зайти в  Rules -> Repository -> выбрать нужный плагин -> экспортнуть правила в нужный профайл.

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения.